# How to call a generic WebApi controller?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement a generic API Controller to be used for all models.

```
public class DefaultController<T> : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/Default
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET: api/Default/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

When I call localhost:xxxxxx/api/Default. It throws error

```
No type was found that matches the controller named 'Default'.
```

Can someone please guide me the correct way to implement.

Also, How do I specify type while calling API?

Thanks.

Comment: Are all generic controllers use the same methods ? and return results the same way, it only differs in the type ?

Comment: This is just one Generic Controller. Here I want to get type which was mentioned while calling and then call that type's repository.

Comment: Maybe you can inherit from a generic controller and pass the type to it instead of pass it while requesting.

`public class DefaultController : MyApiController<MyType>`  
And inside the inherited controller add the methods you want to use
If this works for you let me know to add it as an answer

Comment: How do I controller know whichtype has requested it? and what will be syntax. do you have code sample?

Comment: I Added a code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your `Generic API Controller (Base Controller)`:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DefaultController<T> : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/{ControllerName}
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "first", "second" };
    }

    // GET: api/{ControllerName}/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

You can use the base controller for `Posts`:

```
public class PostsController : DefaultController<Post> {}
```

Or use for others such as `Comments`:

```
public class CommentsController : DefaultController<Comment> {}
```

And you can call controller actions `localhost:xxxx/api/posts`, `localhost:xxxx/api/posts/5`, `localhost:xxxx/api/comments`, `localhost:xxxx/api/comments/12`

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I need. I will implement this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try inherit from a generic base controller instead.

```
public class MyBaseController<T> : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/Default
    public IEnumerable<T> Get()
    {
        return callGenericMethod<T>();
    }
}
```

And now create as many controller as you want:

```
public class DefaultController : MyBaseController<MySpecificType>
{
   //add extra specific methods here or depend on the inherited ones only.
}
```

And calling the controller will be the same as calling none generic one:

```
yourApiPath/Default/Get
```